# Appium 2.0.0: The main Appium script does not exist at '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/build/lib/main.js'

Tags: appium

after uninstalling Appium v1.22 and installing Appium v2.0.0, I see the following error when attempting to run my automated tests.

I'd appreciate your help, and thank you!

```
Test custom report 0
[INFO ] 2023-07-11 13:21:10.503 com.qa.utils.ServerManager:20 - starting appium server

io.appium.java_client.service.local.InvalidServerInstanceException: The main Appium script does not exist at '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/build/lib/main.js'

    at io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumServiceBuilder.validatePath(AppiumServiceBuilder.java:131)
    at io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumServiceBuilder.loadPathToMainScript(AppiumServiceBuilder.java:289)
    at io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumServiceBuilder.createArgs(AppiumServiceBuilder.java:381)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:358)
    at com.qa.utils.ServerManager.startServer(ServerManager.java:26)
    at com.qa.runners.RunnerBase.setUpClass(RunnerBase.java:63)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:62)
    at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:385)
    at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:321)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:176)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:794)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:596)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:377)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.access$000(SuiteRunner.java:28)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$SuiteWorker.run(SuiteRunner.java:418)
    at org.testng.internal.thread.ThreadUtil.lambda$execute$0(ThreadUtil.java:64)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

[Utils] [ERROR] [Error] java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.qa.runners.RunnerBase.scenarios(RunnerBase.java:76)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:77)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodNoCheckedException(MethodInvocationHelper.java:46)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeDataProvider(MethodInvocationHelper.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.handleParameters(Parameters.java:798)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.handleParameters(Parameters.java:740)
    at org.testng.internal.ParameterHandler.handleParameters(ParameterHandler.java:59)
    at org.testng.internal.ParameterHandler.createParameters(ParameterHandler.java:38)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:791)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:794)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:596)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:377)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.access$000(SuiteRunner.java:28)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$SuiteWorker.run(SuiteRunner.java:418)
    at org.testng.internal.thread.ThreadUtil.lambda$execute$0(ThreadUtil.java:64)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)


Test ignored.

===============================================
Suite
Total tests run: 1, Passes: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 1
Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 1
===============================================


Process finished with exit code 0
```

I am expecting the test to run successfully, but it looks like the error message is showing a path for the main Appium script that is different from where it actually is, as shown in the appium logs.

```
user@user-Mac tempo-testng % appium
[Appium] Welcome to Appium v2.0.0 (REV 2b4cfb033757b63ab0b128d01c58db76480956f9)
[Appium] Attempting to load driver uiautomator2...
[debug] [Appium] Requiring driver at /Users/user/.appium/node_modules/appium-uiautomator2-driver
[Appium] Attempting to load driver xcuitest...
[debug] [Appium] Requiring driver at /Users/user/.appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver
[Appium] Attempting to load driver mac2...
[debug] [Appium] Requiring driver at /Users/user/.appium/node_modules/appium-mac2-driver
[Appium] Attempting to load driver safari...
[debug] [Appium] Requiring driver at /Users/user/.appium/node_modules/appium-safari-driver
[Appium] Attempting to load driver chromium...
[debug] [Appium] Requiring driver at /Users/user/.appium/node_modules/appium-chromium-driver
[Appium] Could not load driver 'chromium', so it will not be available. Error in loading the driver was: Cannot find module '@appium/types'
[Appium] Require stack:
[Appium] - /Users/user/.appium/node_modules/appium-chromium-driver/node_modules/@appium/base-driver/build/lib/basedriver/driver.js
[Appium] - /Users/user/.appium/node_modules/appium-chromium-driver/node_modules/@appium/base-driver/build/lib/index.js
[Appium] - /Users/user/.appium/node_modules/appium-chromium-driver/node_modules/@appium/base-driver/index.js
[Appium] - /Users/user/.appium/node_modules/appium-chromium-driver/node_modules/appium-chromedriver/build/lib/chromedriver.js
[Appium] - /Users/user/.appium/node_modules/appium-chromium-driver/node_modules/appium-chromedriver/build/lib/index.js
[Appium] - /Users/user/.appium/node_modules/appium-chromium-driver/build/lib/driver.js
[Appium] - /Users/user/.appium/node_modules/appium-chromium-driver/index.js
[Appium] - /opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/appium/build/lib/extension/extension-config.js
[Appium] - /opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/appium/build/lib/cli/extension-command.js
[Appium] - /opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/appium/build/lib/cli/driver-command.js
[Appium] - /opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/appium/build/lib/cli/extension.js
[Appium] - /opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/appium/build/lib/main.js
[Appium] - /opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/appium/index.js
[debug] [Appium] Error: Cannot find module '@appium/types'
[debug] [Appium] Require stack:
[debug] [Appium] - /Users/user/.appium/node_modules/appium-chromium-driver/node_modules/@appium/base-driver/build/lib/basedriver/driver.js
[debug] [Appium] - /Users/user/.appium/node_modules/appium-chromium-driver/node_modules/@appium/base-driver/build/lib/index.js
[debug] [Appium] - /Users/user/.appium/node_modules/appium-chromium-driver/node_modules/@appium/base-driver/index.js
[debug] [Appium] - /Users/user/.appium/node_modules/appium-chromium-driver/node_modules/appium-chromedriver/build/lib/chromedriver.js
[debug] [Appium] - /Users/user/.appium/node_modules/appium-chromium-driver/node_modules/appium-chromedriver/build/lib/index.js
[debug] [Appium] - /Users/user/.appium/node_modules/appium-chromium-driver/build/lib/driver.js
[debug] [Appium] - /Users/user/.appium/node_modules/appium-chromium-driver/index.js
[debug] [Appium] - /opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/appium/build/lib/extension/extension-config.js
[debug] [Appium] - /opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/appium/build/lib/cli/extension-command.js
[debug] [Appium] - /opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/appium/build/lib/cli/driver-command.js
[debug] [Appium] - /opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/appium/build/lib/cli/extension.js
[debug] [Appium] - /opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/appium/build/lib/main.js
[debug] [Appium] - /opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/appium/index.js
[debug] [Appium]     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1090:15)
[debug] [Appium]     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:934:27)
[debug] [Appium]     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:19)
[debug] [Appium]     at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:119:18)
[debug] [Appium]     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/.appium/node_modules/appium-chromium-driver/node_modules/@appium/base-driver/lib/basedriver/driver.js:18:1)
[debug] [Appium]     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1275:14)
[debug] [Appium]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1329:10)
[debug] [Appium]     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1133:32)
[debug] [Appium]     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:12)
[debug] [Appium]     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:19)
[debug] [Appium]     at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:119:18)
[debug] [Appium]     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/.appium/node_modules/appium-chromium-driver/node_modules/@appium/base-driver/lib/index.js:8:1)
[debug] [Appium]     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1275:14)
[debug] [Appium]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1329:10)
[debug] [Appium]     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1133:32)
[debug] [Appium]     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:12)
[debug] [Appium]     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:19)
[debug] [Appium]     at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:119:18)
[debug] [Appium]     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/.appium/node_modules/appium-chromium-driver/node_modules/@appium/base-driver/index.js:1:18)
[debug] [Appium]     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1275:14)
[debug] [Appium]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1329:10)
[debug] [Appium]     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1133:32)
[debug] [Appium]     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:12)
[debug] [Appium]     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:19)
[debug] [Appium]     at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:119:18)
[debug] [Appium]     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/.appium/node_modules/appium-chromium-driver/node_modules/appium-chromedriver/lib/chromedriver.js:2:1)
[debug] [Appium]     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1275:14)
[debug] [Appium]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1329:10)
[debug] [Appium]     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1133:32)
[debug] [Appium]     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:12)
[debug] [Appium]     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:19)
[debug] [Appium]     at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:119:18)
[debug] [Appium]     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/.appium/node_modules/appium-chromium-driver/node_modules/appium-chromedriver/lib/index.ts:1:1)
[debug] [Appium]     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1275:14)
[debug] [Appium]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1329:10)
[debug] [Appium]     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1133:32)
[debug] [Appium]     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:12)
[debug] [Appium]     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:19)
[debug] [Appium]     at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:119:18)
[debug] [Appium]     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/.appium/node_modules/appium-chromium-driver/lib/driver.js:3:1)
[debug] [Appium]     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1275:14)
[debug] [Appium]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1329:10)
[debug] [Appium]     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1133:32)
[debug] [Appium]     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:12)
[debug] [Appium]     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:19)
[debug] [Appium]     at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:119:18)
(node:36827) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 exit listeners added to [process]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
[Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on http://0.0.0.0:4723
[Appium] You can provide the following URLS in your client code to connect to this server:
[Appium]        http://127.0.0.1:4723/ (only accessible from the same host)
[Appium]        http://192.168.1.4:4723/
[Appium] Available drivers:
[Appium]   - uiautomator2@2.29.2 (automationName 'UiAutomator2')
[Appium]   - xcuitest@4.32.14 (automationName 'XCUITest')
[Appium]   - mac2@1.6.3 (automationName 'Mac2')
[Appium]   - safari@3.3.3 (automationName 'Safari')
[Appium]   - chromium@1.1.31 (automationName 'Chromium')
[Appium] Available plugins:
[Appium]   - execute-driver@3.0.14
[Appium]   - images@2.1.2
[Appium]   - relaxed-caps@1.0.5
[Appium] No plugins activated. Use the --use-plugins flag with names of plugins to activate
```

Comment: Hey! Can you please install appium using npm like as, `npm i --location=global appium` form the root directory of your terminal and see if this is working fine?

Answer (score 0):

I got the issue after installing nvm
it moves the default node path to .nvm
that's why appium can't be found

1. find the appium path "which appium"
2. find the main.js in that path
3. add the path in the method .withAppiumJS

in my case

```
        builder = new AppiumServiceBuilder()
            .withCapabilities(options)
            .withIPAddress("127.0.0.1")
            .withAppiumJS(new File("//Users/antonio.aguilar/.nvm/versions/node/v20.11.1/lib/node_modules/appium/build/lib/main.js"))
            .usingAnyFreePort();
```

it works for me